# simple simulation displays a IndexError: index x is out of bounds for axis 0 with size x

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

I am implementing the following code to simulate probabilities.

The code is:

```
## Simulate 

simulations = 4
samp_size = 5
B = 50
deme_config = [0. 1. 0. 1. 0.]

w = np.zeros((simulations, samp_size,samp_size))
b = np.zeros((simulations, samp_size,samp_size))
p = np.zeros((simulations, samp_size,samp_size))
p_bar = np.zeros((simulations, samp_size,samp_size))


for sim in range(simulations):
    
    p_bar[sim] = 0.0
    w[sim] = 0.0
    b[sim] = 0.0
    w_tot = 0.0
    b_tot = 0.0
    
    # Induce independence 
    for b in range(B):
        bsim = np.random.randint(int(simulations-1), size=samp_size)
        for i in range(samp_size): 
            for j in range(samp_size):
                p[i,j] += p_block[bsim][i,j]
                p_bar[sim] += (p_block[bsim][i,j])*2/samp_size/(samp_size-1)
                if(deme_config[i]==deme_config[j]): 
                    w[sim] += p_block[bsim][i,j]
                    w_tot += 1
                else:
                    b[sim] += p_block[bsim][i,j]
                    b_tot += 1

    w[sim] *= B/w_tot
    b[sim] *= B/b_tot

    # Make matrix symmetric
    
    for i in range(samp_size):
        for j in range(samp_size):
            p[j,i] = p[i,j]
```

where p_block is:

```
print(p_block)
```

```
[[[0. 2. 1. 1. 2.]
  [0. 2. 0. 0. 1.]
  [1. 0. 2. 0. 1.]
  [2. 0. 0. 1. 2.]
  [4. 2. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[2. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [4. 2. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 0. 2. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 2. 4.]]

 [[1. 2. 0. 0. 1.]
  [1. 3. 1. 2. 1.]
  [1. 3. 0. 0. 0.]
  [2. 0. 4. 1. 2.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[2. 0. 1. 0. 2.]
  [2. 2. 1. 1. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 2. 0.]
  [1. 1. 3. 4. 1.]
  [2. 1. 3. 2. 3.]]]
```

However when I run this code, sometimes I get this error that

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-03ea6d20b771> in <module>
---> 41                 p[i,j] += p_block[bsim][i,j]
     42                 p_bar[sim] += (p_block[bsim][i,j])*2/samp_size/(samp_size-1)
     43                 if(deme_config[i]==deme_config[j]):

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

I cannot understand why the p_lock sum cannot be stored on p if they have identical dimensions.

```
print(p.shape)
print(p_block.shape)
```

```
(4, 5, 5)
(4, 5, 5)
```

Can anyone give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Hopefully someone can help me, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you name all valid indices for an array with size 4?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question well. Could you explain to me a little bit more what do you mean?

Comment: With `simulations = 3` and `samp_size = 4`, how are you getting (4, 5, 5) from `p = np.zeros((simulations, samp_size, samp_size))`?

Comment: You are doing `p[i,j]`.  Your `i` loop runs to `samp_size`, but that dimension is sized to `simulations`.  Did you want `p[bsim,i,j]` there?

Comment: ddejohn was right! I ran many examples that I made a mistake when I pasted the example, I edited it with the dimensions I put before. I reran it. I still have the same problem.

Comment: Tim Roberts, I want both of them. First, I would like each entry on the matrix to have assigned the values that correspond from p_block at each bsim, then p_bar would be the sum per simulation of those values (p_block).